# Using python regex to find a specific pattern within a limited-character string

Tags: python

I'm learning Python regex. I've read some resources and watched some online tutorials, plus read some of the Q&As on here, but I'm finding it rather challenging.

I'm trying to write a `re.match()` that looks for these simple following criteria:

- The string must be between 5 to 15 characters long.
- Those characters must be `[a-z]`.
- The string cannot have two or more adjacent "a's", though it can have two or more adjacent `[b-z]` characters.

Examples of matches and non-matches:

```
"happy"            # Match 
"haapy"            # Not a match (two adjacent "a's")
"happay"           # Match
"happppppppyyyyy   # Match (15 characters)
"Happppppyyyyyyyy  # Not a match (16 characters)
"happy!"           # Not a match (contains "!")
"happy1"           # Not a match (contains a number)
```

Problem is, I'm not sure how to write a regex that (a) limits that number of characters a string can contain and (b) does not allow for a specific sub-string pattern -- in this case, two or more adjacent "a" characters.

I have the basic pattern started (see below).

```
^[a-z]{1,32}$
```

Would I consider a negative lookahead -- (?!aa)? How should I think about this problem? Thanks for your help, and apologies if the question is too simple or premature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you already know the answer - negative lookahead!
`^((?!aa)[a-z]){5,15}$`

test codes:

```py
import re

strings = [
    "happy",  # Match
    "haapy",  # Not a match (two adjacent "a's")
    "happay",  # Match
    "happppppppyyyyy",  # Match (15 characters)
    "Happppppyyyyyyyy",  # Not a match (16 characters)
    "happy!",  # Not a match (contains "!")
    "happy1",  # Not a match (contains a number)
    "aaaaa",
    "bbbaa",
    "aabbb",
]

for string in strings:
    print('Match!' if re.match('^((?!aa)[a-z]){5,15}$', string) else 'Not a match.')
```

output:

```
Match!
Not a match.
Match!
Match!
Not a match.
Not a match.
Not a match.
Not a match.
Not a match.
Not a match.
```

I added some cases-trailing or heading "aa".

Comment: Thanks much -- that solved my problem. I figured that negative look-ahead seemed sensible, but I wasn't sure how to write it. What you've done makes sense!